# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'switch_to_window_handles'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write this code using Selenium and Python to skip to next windows of browser:

```
browser.switch_to_window_handles(browser.window_handles[-1])
```

But I don't understand why this error occured, please help me

error: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'switch_to_window_handles'

Comment: does your `browser` have the right reference to the selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
```

Comment: -solution works